# How to control the Kinect motor with ROS Groovy

Tags: control, ros, kinect, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi at all,

i want to control the motor of the Kinect in my ROS node but i don't know how to do so.
After a google search i wanted to use kinect_aux, but that isn't available in Groovy.
Is there another way to do what i want?

Thanks in advance!

Greets
Felsi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64466/how-to-control-the-kinect-motor-with-ros-groovy/) by [Felsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5071/felsi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use http://fsstud.is.uni-due.de/ubuntu/dists/custom/main/binary-amd64/is-groovy-kinect-aux_2013.06.07.11.04_amd64.deb

It is tested with ubuntu 12.04 64Bit. If you use an other OS or you don't trust me, you can download this deb file and extract it. You will find everything you need (package.xml, CMakeLists.txt, kinect_aux.cpp) to recompile it.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2